# Unable to alter column name

Tags: oracle12c

I am unable to alter column name in oracle 12c

Below is my Table structure :-

```
ORDER_ID                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
RX_IMAGE1                                 NOT NULL BLOB
RX_IMAGE3                                 NOT NULL BLOB
RX_IMAGE4                                 NOT NULL BLOB
CREATE_DATE_TIME                          NOT NULL DATE
LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME                     NOT NULL DATE
RX_IMAGE2                                 NOT NULL BLOB
```

I want to change RX_IMAGE1 `"not null"` to `"null"`

Comment: What do you mean by you're unable to do it?  What statement are you running? What error is it throwing?

Comment: Changing a column from not-nullable to nullable isn't the same as changing its name, which is what your title and first line suggest you are trying to do. We need to see what you are doing and what happens, so we can correct what may be a misunderstanding of the syntax.

Comment: I am trying below query :-

ALTER TABLE PRESCRIPTION_IMAGES MODIFY RX_IMAGE3 BLOB NULL;
                                       
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the data type (and cannot do so), so remove that from the command:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE PRESCRIPTION_IMAGES MODIFY RX_IMAGE3 NULL; 

Table altered.
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=12b523fb14b8b45e7d1ff30027794aea)